# Project Structure for Data Application with ASP.Net Core

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am building an application that hits a database and does some stuff and I want to make sure I am building my solution and project structure correctly. The application will be exposed via WebApi using ASP.Net Core using .Net Framework. I have a class library that I will use to interact with the database (using EF6) and want to make sure I am configuring the startup right to make sure my Controllers will be able to call into the DB though that layer. In the past, all i really had to do was reference the CL and add the connection string to the Web.config. Since now I am using appsettings.json to store my connection string, how do I wire up the DI to make sure all calls to the service layer have that connection string?

Comment: Take a look in [working with data](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/index.html) section from microsoft docs.

Comment: So is EF Designer from Database no longer supported? The constructors are generated and seems aren't similar to what DI needs.